# Яндекс Карты во вкладке

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Всем доброго времени суток. Пишу сайт на react, использую yandex api maps для указания адреса. Яндекс карты располагаются не на отдельной странице, а на вкладке. При переключении вкладки на карты и обратно, выходит ошибка:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'modules')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'modules')

В документации нашёл, что при создании карты в options нужно указать autoFitToViewport с параметром ifNull или always. Но мне это не помогло. Не знаю, что дальше с этим делать. Уже несколько месяцев пытаюсь научиться их использовать) Заранее спасибо за ответ

Как объявляю карты

```
const defaultState = {
            center: [54.31800414150244, 48.39647750793459],
            zoom: 14,
            controls: ["zoomControl", "fullscreenControl"],
        };

        const defaultOptions = {
            autoFitToViewport: "ifNull",
        };

        const myMap = new ymaps.Map(ref.current, defaultState, defaultOptions);
```

Comment: А можете ваш пример на codesandbox.io собрать с демонстрацией текущей проблемы? Или это только на вашем окружении воспроизводится?

Comment: Не смог запустить. У меня в проекте есть json сервер. Не знаю, как его запустить на sandblox

Comment: А упрощённый вариант нельзя собрать? Минимальный пример — на то и минимальный. У вас ведь на начальных этапах проблема возникает. Попробуйте минимальное подключение без лишних данных и пакетов собрать.

Comment: Вроде получилось. [https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/practical-fog-36qp6l?welcome=true]